# How can I merge two SimpleCursorAdapters in Android?

Tags: android, sql, cursor, simplecursoradapter

I am using two SimpleCursorAdapters to display text and images in a row in my Listview. The problem is that when calling these Adapters two times they conflict with each other. In the end my Listview only shows the data of the SimpleCursorAdapter that I called last.

What I need to do is merge those two SimpleCursorAdapters although they use different sql databases.

Any ideas to solve this??

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.reminder_list);
    mDbHelper = new RemindersDbAdapter(this);
    mImageHelper = new ImageAdapter(this);
    mDbHelper.open();
    mImageHelper.open();
    fillData();
    fillImages();
    registerForContextMenu(getListView());
}

//
// Fills the ListView with the data from the SQLite Database.
//
private void fillData() {
    Cursor remindersCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllReminders();
    startManagingCursor(remindersCursor);

    // Creates an array with the task title.
    String[] from = new String[] {RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE, RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_BODY};

    // Creates an array for the text.
    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.text1, R.id.text2};

    // SimpleCursorAdapter which is displayed.
    SimpleCursorAdapter reminders = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.reminder_row, remindersCursor, from, to);
    setListAdapter(reminders);

}

//
// Fills the ListView with the images from the SQLite Database.
//
private void fillImages() {
    Cursor imageCursor = mImageHelper.fetchAllImages();
    startManagingCursor(imageCursor);

    // Creates an array with the image path.
    String[] fromImage = new String[] {ImageAdapter.KEY_IMAGE};

    // Creates an array for the text.
    int[] toImage = new int[] {R.id.icon};

    // SimpleCursorAdapter which is displayed.
    SimpleCursorAdapter images = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.reminder_row, imageCursor, fromImage, toImage);
    setListAdapter(images);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [MergeCursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MergeCursor.html) class to expose a number of individual cursors as a single cursor. As your adapters bind different columns->widgets, you may have to write your own subclass of SimpleCursorAdapter (or just CursorAdapter) so that you can do the correct type of binding depending on the row.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to implement such a MergeCursor? I have never used it before.

Answer (score 0):

how about creating your own adapter (extend BaseAdapter) , which will point to the correct data each time it needs to ?
this way you can have full control over when and where to show each item.

you can even use the 2 adapters and use them for the new adapter.

Answer (score 0):

> What I need to do is merge those two SimpleCursorAdapters although they use different sql databases.

If the two adapters are truly different (e.g., different row layouts), use [my `MergeAdapter`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge) to combine your two existing adapters into one, then use the `MergeAdapter` with your `ListView`.

However, in your case, it would appear that you simply have two `Cursors` with different contents, in which case superfell's answer of using `MergeCursor` is probably a better approach.